# Edit form in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, edit

I'm trying to edit a Modelform with an "edit" button but the form isn't updated. I have one view-function, original for posting and saving a new post. Then I have a second function, `edit_comment`, for updating the object `one_entry` that is created in original. In my template I have one form for submitting posts and an "edit" button connected to url "/edit" to update the added `one_entry` objects from the form with url "/entry". Any help is greatly appriciated.

in views

```
# function for adding a new post
def original(request, postID):
    one_entry = Entry.objects.get(id=postID)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReplyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            postOneComment(request, one_entry)

    else:
        form = ReplyForm()

    c = {"one_entry":one_entry,"form":form,"comment_views":comment_views}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render(request,"template.html", c)


# function for editing/updating the object one_entry
# Comment is a model and content and title are fields in the Modelform 
# that should be updated
def edit_comment(request, one_entry):
    content = Comment.objects.get(pk=one_entry)
    title = Comment.objects.get(pk=one_entry)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReplyForm(request.POST, instance=content)
        form = ReplyForm(request.POST, instance=title)
        if form.is_valid():
            postOneComment(request, one_entry)

    else:
        form = ReplyForm()

    c = {"form":form,"one_entry":one_entry}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render(request,"template.html", c)


def postOneComment(request, one_entry):
    content = request.POST["content"]

    title = request.POST["title"]



    user= request.user.username


    entryComment = Comment(datetime=datetime.datetime.now(), belongsTo=one_entry,content=content, title=title, user=user)
    entryComment.save()
```

in forms

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ("title","content", "user")
```

in urls

```
# url for adding a post to object one_entry 
url(r'^entry(?P<postID>\d+)$', original),

# url for editing/updating one_entry  
url(r'^edit(?P<one_entry>\d+)$',edit_comment),
```

in template

```
#button for editing one_entry
{% for t in one_entry.comment_set.all %}
    <a type="button" href="/edit{{ t.id}}" class="btn btn-xs   btn-success">EDIT</button></a>

    #form for adding  a new post
    <form  method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        <center>Titel (optional){{ form.title}}</center></br>
        <center>{{ form.content}}</center>
        <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">POST</button></center>
    </form>
```

Comment: What is `post_one_comment`? And why do you define a form in `edit_comment` and then immediately replace it with a different form?

Comment: added it now under the views - section, its for posting the view -function in the template and save the form. I'm not sure how to use "instance" in another way.

Comment: But what you've written is the same as `foo = "bar"; foo = "baz"` - the first variable is defined and then replaced, and foo is just equal to "baz". There is no point in defining it as equal to "bar" in the first place.

Comment: And now I don't understand what the point of `postOneComment` is. You've carefully defined a form and instantiated it with an instance, now you've defined a separate function that completely *ignores* the form and saves a comment directly from the POST. Why are you doing this?

Comment: ok, I wasn't aware of that, how can I update the form fields with the instance variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are at least three issues here.

Firstly, as I say, your repeated instantiation of the `form` variable is pointless; it's as if you never did the first one at all. So don't.

Secondly, I don't understand what the point of `postOneComment` is. You've carefully defined a form and instantiated it with an instance, now you've defined a separate function that completely ignores the form and saves a comment directly from the POST. This code wouldn't actually work, in fact, because you try to pass the *username* string as the `user` parameter instead of the actual user.

Thirdly, the actual problem you are having is that your form is not valid. However, you don't show the errors on the template, so you don't see them - and you also don't redirect to another URL after a successful post, so you have no way of telling whether the post is successful or not.

The reason your form is not valid is that you explicitly include the `user` parameter in the form, but then don't supply it on the template. So that form will never be valid. Clearly you want to set it automatically, so remove it from `fields`.

So, to summarise:

- Remove `user` from the form fields;
- Add `{{ form.errors }}` to your template;
- Replace your view code with this:

.

```
def edit_comment(request, one_entry):
    content = Comment.objects.get(pk=one_entry)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReplyForm(request.POST, instance=content)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/')  # or wherever you want
    else:
        form = ReplyForm()
    c = {"form":form,"one_entry": content}
    return render(request,"template.html", c)
```

Comment: thanks, it works with this instead of the post -function as you said.